# How do I delete my FreeSO account?

Tags: account-management

Last year I made a FreeSO (https://freeso.org) account to play with a friend, but now I don't want to keep it around any more. However, I can't seem to figure out how to actually delete my account. How can I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FreeSO requires you to get the attention of an admin to delete your account. I did this through their Discord guild/server (linked on their website), but it may be possible to do it through other means such as their forum as well.